# I want to change the size of the bound by place in UI Scroll View of iOS7

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios7

I am developing the application of iOS7 now

I want to change the size of the bound by object in UI Scroll View of iOS7.

I also want to change the color of the margin bound view

How can i do?

Comment: What do you mean by changing the color of margin bound view?

Comment: Sorry.color of bound view

Comment: Use `setBackgroundColor` to set the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by change the size of the bound, you mean placing lots of views inside scrollview beyond its frame size, then you can do that and just set the `contentSize` property of `UIScrollView`. Make the `contentSize`[(link here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) as much as you want the scrollView to scroll.

Have a look at the documentation for various properties of `UIScrollView` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

Comment: Thank you. And I'm sorry.
I'm Japanese.
And I can't write English well.

Comment: Thats alright. Did you get it to work?

Comment: I want to color different from the color of the main view of the color of the bound view.

Comment: Set the backgroundColor of your scrollView, that way you can have different background color of scrollView than the main view. For example -> `[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];`

Comment: sorry.I use UITableView.And I can't use this way.

Comment: You can try setting a `UIView` as background view for tableView by `setBackgroundView:` and change the color of that.